# Syntax error in react-boilerplate after adding new dependencies

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-hmr, react-boilerplate

I have a hard time adding dependencies to a newly generated react-boilerplate project. I face this error:

```
node.js:122 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
(anonymous function)    @   reactBoilerplateDeps.dll.js:340
__webpack_require__ @   reactBoilerplateDeps.dll.js:21
(anonymous function)    @   application.js:7
...
```

after adding this dependency to package.json like this:

```
"feathers-client": "^1.6.1",
```

and to an existing index.html such as app/containers/App/index.js

```
import feathers from 'feathers-client';
```

If I remove the import statement from index.js the error disappears.

I have no clue what is happening so any suggestion will be appreciated.

**Some more details:**

I started cloning this repository:

https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate

Then I ran npm run setup. Then I added the dependency to feathers-client and I get the error.

I should also mention that I get similar errors when I add dependencies such as request, feathers-rest and request-promise.

I do not face the error if I add dependencies such as bluebird.

I haven't found a clear pattern into what dependencies gives this error.

Comment: Wouldn't `import feathers from 'bluebird'` import the wrong package? Is your webpack config excluding node_modules from being compiled by Babel?

Comment: The line "import feathers from 'bluebird' " was my mistake. Thx for pointing it out. It did not really fix the problem, just somehow hide it. Sorry for confusing. I have edited my question once again to state the original problem.

Comment: You ask: Is your webpack config excluding node_modules from being compiled by Babel? I don't really know. I can't find the webpack config file anywhere.

Comment: What boilerplate are you using?

Comment: I added some more details to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue is caused by `import feathers from "feathers-client"` resolving `node_modules/feathers-client/lib/client.js` instead of the pre-compiled `node_modules/feathers-client/dist/feathers.js`. To fix this, use:

```
import feathers from "feathers-client/dist/feathers"
```

Comment: Wow, that worked!! How did you figure that out? And thx, I will try to move on from here.